# ChromeCast audio player repositioning itself

Tags: ios, ios7, chromecast, google-cast

Developing and Application using ChromeCast to play audio files using Styled Media Receiver. Everything is working fine except the audio player view reposition itself after some interval. I want the view should always be on the initial position i.e. on the bottom left corner as shown in the attached image.

[image]

Another thing is that when we stop playing the audio (Pause State), the progress bar appears on full screen. It will be better if I can display the progress bar on whole screen all the time.

Please suggest your valuable opinions. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The album art moves around to prevent screen burn-in. If you want to change the layout and behavior of the receiver then create your own custom receiver. Use the reference receiver as the starting point since it supports audio playback: https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample